# react-virtualized notification when List gets focus

Tags: react-virtualized

When a user tabs into a List and the List gets focus I want to put a border around the List's parent.  It would be great if I could call onFocus/onBlur on the List.  Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there is no way to attach `onBlur` or `onFocus` events (or anything other than `onScroll`) to a `Grid`. (The same is true for `List` which just decorates a `Grid`).

You could add this behavior yourself using the `ref` though. Here is an example Plnkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/TVxnhf?p=preview

The key part is:

```
  _setListRef(listRef) {
    if (listRef) {
      listRef = findDOMNode(listRef);
      listRef.addEventListener('blur', onListBlur);
      listRef.addEventListener('focus', onListFocus);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Wow - perfect.  Thank you very much.