# How could I get a reference to list ref and to element ref?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-virtualized

I'm migrating a chat component to use vitualized react, but in my current implementation I need to use the listRef that contains *recomputeRowHeights*, *forceUpdate*, *forceUpdateGrid*. Because in my implementation, a message is not a single item, but a bunch of messages sent in the last 5 seconds. So the row height is increased, but the list height isn't.

```
<div class="item">
  <div>
   //user's information
  </div>
  <div>
   <div class="message">
   </div>
   // repeat to the last messages sent
  </div>
</div>
```

The way that I found to adjust the list height was looking when the count of the last messages change, so I recompute the last row and request to update the list height, without it the row height increase and the row isn't shown in full.

But in the current implementation to know if the message was read or not we add a event to the scoll and to resize and calculate if the item is in the viewport, So i need to access to element ref to call the addEventListner. 
I found this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44188298/react-virtualized-notification-when-list-gets-focus), but using that way I can found a way to access the list ref.